# Как сделать объект не зависимым от родителя через скрипт в юнити?

Tags: unity3d

У меня какой-то объект object, и он дочерний к объекту parent. Мне через скрипт нужно сделать так что-бы object больше не был дочерним к parent. Он должен быть самостоятельным.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Чтобы объект был независимым от родителя, объекту нужно найти работу и обеспечивать себя самому.

Answer (score 2):

```
transform.parent = null;
```

Тогда объект станет 'самостоятельным' :)